# Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /home/abc/public_html/wp-content/themes/abc/footer.php on line 70

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get, product

When I open the website, I get an error in the footer

Notice: Undefined index: product_id in /home/abc/public_html/wp-content/themes/abc/footer.php on line 70

Here is the related code generating this error:

```
<?php wp_footer(); 
if($_GET['product_id']&&$_GET['product_id']!=""){
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="'.$product_id.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_name" value="'.get_the_title($product_id).'" />';
}
?>
```

Can anybody help to fix this issue, I checked with all the php.in and plugins issue, but I found no issue in plugin.

Comment: Did you tried my answer code? Some feedback on it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This code will help you

```
if( $_REQUEST['product_id'] && $_REQUEST['product_id'] != "" ){
    $product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="'.$product_id.'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_name" value="'.get_the_title( $product_id ).'" />';
}
```

Comment: Didint worked brother

Answer (score 0):

Always use `isset()` on a `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` variable in an if statement, to avoid this kind of error, when the variable is not defined. So replace with:

```php
<?php wp_footer(); 
if( isset($_GET['product_id']) && ! empty($_GET['product_id']) ){
    $product_id = intval($_GET['product_id']);
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="'.$product_id.'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="product_name" value="'.get_the_title($product_id).'" />';
}
?>
```

It should solve this issue.